# Safari ignore "expire" cookie directive

Tags: php, cookies, safari, setcookie

Safari on MAC, iPhone and iPad is ignoring expire directive of cookie creation and it clear cookies after closing the browser, can you please explain why, and how can i resolve this issue.

This is the php code that i use to create cookie.

```
setcookie('cookie_test', 'cookie_data', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 720, "/", ".domain.com");
```

Thank you

Comment: This can be set in the browser settings! Did you check there

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the problem is not on my side, what I would like is that cookies remain stored on the browser of my website visitors.

Comment: Yes, but your visitors use THEIR browser, and therefore THEY have control over whether cookies are allowed to be stored. I can set my browser to delete all cookies when I close the browser. It sounds like this is what is happening

Comment: In short, you are not in control of cookie storage on my browser

Comment: yes i know all that, what i need to know is why is safari delete cookies by default, unlike other browsers, and if there is something i can do from the server side to prevent that, because I noticed that it does not delete cookies from other sites like google.com for example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I am not sure if this would be appropriate for your case. But deleting the cookie from the backend seems to work.

So from the client you send a request to the server and delete the cookies or update them on the response.